# How would you structure Zend_Auth & Zend_Acl in Zend Framework to obey having a Thin Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, oop, zend-framework

There has been a fair bit of talk/debate lately in the Zend Framework community about thin controllers. Apparently there is a tendency of ZF users to view the Model as nothing more than the gateway to the database.

The argument is that Models should be "fat" and do more of the work and Controllers shouldn't be chaining methods and doing much work beyond conveying the meaning of the UI to the model.

For some references follow the links in this post:

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html

Along the same lines, I think it's easy to let Zend_Acl and Zend_Auth overtake your controllers and turn them into a complex mess.

I'm building a site right now that requires an admin section and before writing that code, I thought I'd try to get a good discussion/debate started on how best to structure authorization and access control, with a particular eye to well tested methodologies from the OOP world.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution is Front Controller Plugin. In routeShutdown() method (i.e. first moment when you have the request object) you check the ACL and / or redirect to login controller.

Comment: And if you need calling restricted action in non-restricted controllers you should move the code to predispatch.

Comment: Interesting. I'll need to research routeShutdown().

Comment: I'm having a tough time figuring out how and where to register the front controller plugin. Do I have to modify the new Bootstrap.php?

Comment: Yes, you do. Use `$front->registerPlugin($pluginInstance);`

Comment: I don't totaly agree with this response, it is a valid answer however, but it only applies to simple use case, most people see "resource" == "controller" (or action) but you may have more complex acl where your resource can be anything, and in that case you can't rely on a front controller plugin because you're not able to provide anything else than a request object to the Acl module. I'll go for an AuthorizationService which extends Zend_Acl, it's a little more work, especially when you need to redirect user to an error/login page but it's worth to do it.

Comment: You are right. My proposed solution is not flexible when your resources are not 1:1 mapped to MVC. But ic can be easily "hacked" into having some entry point to use from inside actions when JIT ACL control is required.